# Поиск элемента в массиве по значению поля объекта [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть массив объектов. Выглядит следующим образом:

```
const array = [
    {
      id: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
    },
  ];
```

**Вопрос**. Как мне узнать индекс элемента с ID 2, например?
В JS есть функция из коробки? Всё перерыл, не могу найти.

**Собственноручный** перебор элементов циклом **не** подойдёт!

Comment: Не знаю как вы искали https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findInde. Но под капотом там всё равно цикл

Comment: А ты думаешь функция из коробки не использует цикл?

Comment: @СергейМишин Использует, конечно. Но функция из коробки использует его гараздо эффективней, нежели я + кода меньше в разы. Мне нужно решить свою проблему в одну лишь строку :) 
И благодаря ответам ниже у меня получилось.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Да знаю я, что цикл под капотом)

Comment: Поправил вопрос темы, думаю, теперь понятней о чём я.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть! См [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). Указывается предикат, на выходе `-1` или порядковый номер начиная с `0`

Answer (score 0):

[findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

---

*Тело сообщения должно содержать не менее 30 символов; вы ввели 9.*